# 500 Internal Server error on a single PHP file

Tags: php, runtime-error

Today I finished working on a new PHP script that handles AJAX requests from comments and it adds new votes automatically.
(I commented the first includes to see if they changed something, but they don't)

```
<?php

/*include_once 'functions.php';

include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';*/

sec_session_start();

$azione = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'a', $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$da = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'd', $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$su = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 's', $filter = FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if(!is_numeric($azione)){
    exit();
}

if(!is_numeric($da)){
    exit();
}

if(!is_numeric($su)){
    exit();
}

$azione = (int) $azione;
$da = (int) $da;
$su = (int) $su;

/*
 * Le azioni che possiamo utilizzare sono 3:
 * 1: VOTE UP
 * 2: VOTE DOWN 
 * 3: SEGNALAZIONE
 * 
 * Tuttavia per identificare, dalla variabile $azione ci saranno 5 possibilià.
 * 1: Vote up
 * 2: Remove vote up
 * 3: Vote down
 * 4: Remove vote down
 * 5: Segnalazione
 */

/*
 * Nel caso di un vote UP:
 * Eliminiamo ogni vote down
 * poi aggiungiamo il vote up.
 * DELETE FROM `azioni` WHERE `Tipo Azione` = 2 AND `Su` = ? AND `Da` = ?
 */ 
if($azione == 1) {
    $delete_stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("DELETE FROM `azioni` WHERE `Tipo Azione` = 2 AND `Su` = ? AND `Da` = ?");
    $delete_stmt -> bind_param ('ii', $su, $da);

    $delete_stmt -> execute();
    $delete_stmt -> store_result();

    // Ora che abbiamo eliminato il votedown aggiungiamo il voteup.
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `azioni` (`Tipo Azione`, `Da`, `Su`, `Data`) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', ?);");            
    $now_time = time();             
    $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $azione, $da, $su, $now_time);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    // Finito.
    echo 1;
} else if($azione == 2) {
    // Nel caso in cui l'azione è 2, dobbiamo eliminare il vote up.
    $delete_stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("DELETE FROM `azioni` WHERE `Tipo Azione` = 1 AND `Su` = ? AND `Da` = ?");
    $delete_stmt -> bind_param ('ii', $su, $da);

    $delete_stmt -> execute();
    $delete_stmt -> store_result();

    // Finito.
    echo 1;
} else if($azione == 3) {
    $delete_stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("DELETE FROM `azioni` WHERE `Tipo Azione` = 1 AND `Su` = ? AND `Da` = ?");
    $delete_stmt -> bind_param ('ii', $su, $da);

    $delete_stmt -> execute();
    $delete_stmt -> store_result();

    // L'azione deve diventare 2 perchè 3 non corrisponde al votedown.
    $azione = 2;

    // Ora che abbiamo eliminato il voteup aggiungiamo il votedown.
    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO `azioni` (`Tipo Azione`, `Da`, `Su`, `Data`) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', ?);");          
    $now_time = time();             
    $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $azione, $da, $su, $now_time);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    // Finito.
    echo 1;
} else if($azione == 4) {
    // Nel caso in cui l'azione è 4, dobbiamo eliminare il vote down.
    $delete_stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("DELETE FROM `azioni` WHERE `Tipo Azione` = 2 AND `Su` = ? AND `Da` = ?");
    $delete_stmt -> bind_param ('ii', $su, $da);

    $delete_stmt -> execute();
    $delete_stmt -> store_result();

    // Finito.
    echo 1;
} else if($azione == 5){
    // L'azione deve essere 3 perchè è quella della segnalazione.
    $azione = 3;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `azioni` (`Tipo Azione`, `Da`, `Su`, `Data`) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', ?);");            
    $now_time = time();             
    $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $azione, $da, $su, $now_time);

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    // Finito.
    echo 1;
}
```

Right now it doesn't work; in fact when I try to load the page I get a 500 internal server error and if I go in the server log I get these two errors:

```
[Tue Feb 17 12:58:25 2015] [error] [client ip.ip.ip.ip:port] - www.website.it - End of script output before headers: action-comment.php
[Tue Feb 17 12:58:25 2015] [error] [client ip.ip.ip.ip:port] - www.website.it - AH01215: suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
```

I have never had this error before, and it just shows up on this specific page.
What can be the solution?

Comment: are you using .htaccess ?

Comment: In all the website there are just 2 .htaccess files

Comment: try removing .htaccess files and check

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I discovered that the problem was caused by Aptana 3 doing something wrong; in fact if I try to create a new file inside the software and then upload it, it will always return error 500.

Instead, if I create the file from FileZilla, it works like a charm.